# Translate in runtime with angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I need to do a setting menu and from there, reload a new translation that I have in a local folder, in the .config of my main module, I load a default language

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider,cargarIdiomas) {
      $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('es');
      $translateProvider.useLoader('cargarIdiomas');
    }])
```

I have the cargarIdiomas factory where through a $http i got my es.json so now Im in the choose language view, where i have a list of language, and i want that wehere I pick up a language, can load the new language selected, is there a way how i can do that?... my view got a new controller where i have the function

```
cambiarLanguage(lang)
{
    $translate.use(lan); 
}
```

but i guess it doesnt work cause the controller where I make the configuration and where I try to update the language are not the same, so it lost the data or something, hope you guys can help me